# What is the different between mask, label in Custom data generator

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, semantic-segmentation

I am trying to build custom datagenerator.

I noticed most writings return one-hot-label file instead of one-hot-mask file.I always thought they were the same thing.

I have image.npy files that were generated by cuting using mask files and mask.npy files

Should I return mask file?  What is the different between mask and label?

Here is my datagenerator, but in get_data have some problem about y.(in here, label_folders is mask folders)

```
class CustomDataGenerator(Sequence):
    def __init__(self, image_folders, label_folders, dim=(512,512),  batch_size=1, n_classes=7, n_channels=18, shuffle=True):
        self.image_folders = image_folders
        self.label_folders = label_folders
        self.dim = dim
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.n_classes = n_classes
        self.n_channels = n_channels
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.image_paths = []
        self.label_paths = []
        self.on_epoch_end()
        
    def __len__(self):
        return int(np.ceil(len(self.image_paths) / self.batch_size))  


    def __getitem__(self, index):
        batch_image_paths = self.image_paths[index * self.batch_size: (index + 1) * self.batch_size]
        batch_label_paths = self.label_paths[index * self.batch_size: (index + 1) * self.batch_size]
        
        batch = zip(batch_image_paths, batch_label_paths)
        return self.get_data(batch)
    
    def on_epoch_end(self):
        self.image_paths = []
        for folder in self.image_folders:
            image_folder_path = os.path.join('data/syu/npy', folder)
            image_files = os.listdir(image_folder_path)
            for file_name in image_files:
                self.image_paths.append(os.path.join(image_folder_path, file_name))

        for folder in self.label_folders:
            label_folder_path = os.path.join('data/syu/npy', folder)
            label_files = os.listdir(label_folder_path)
            for file_name in label_files:
                self.label_paths.append(os.path.join(label_folder_path, file_name))
                
        if self.shuffle:
            np.random.shuffle(self.image_paths)
            np.random.shuffle(self.label_paths)

    def get_data(self, batch):
        X = np.empty((self.batch_size, *self.dim, self.n_channels))
        y = np.empty((self.batch_size), dtype=int)
        for i, (image_path, label_path) in enumerate(batch):
            image = np.load(image_path)
            label = np.load(label_path)
            
            X[i,] = image
            y[i] = label
            
        return X, keras.utils.to_categorical(y, num_classes=self.n_classes)
```